# Popup information "attachment is too big"

Tags: sharepoint-online, attachments

Is there any way to provide user information about attachments?

For example: "Can not upload attachments - limit 5MB."

Comment: Where do you want this? On SharePoint default list forms or customized list forms or in SPFx web part?

Answer (score 1):

You can meet your needs through Power Apps:

1.Go to the list, click on **Integrate** >> **Power Apps** >> **Customize forms**

[image]

2.The page is redirected to the Power Apps, select **DataCardValue4**.

3.On the DataCardValue4 Information panel, click on "**Advanced**" and find "**MaxAttachmentSize**" parameter. Set the value of "MaxAttachmentSize" is 5.

- MaxAttachmentSize – The maximum allowed file size in MB of each new attachment. Currently there is a limit of 50 MB.

[image]

4.Click **File** >> **Save** >> **Publish to SharePoint**

[image]

5.Go back list, when you upload an attachment, the following will occur(In my environment, I set it to 1MB):

[image]